# Draw object's future path swift

Tags: swift, path, sprite-kit

I'm working with Xcode, using swift and spritekit, and I would like to know how to draw an object's future path based on its velocity and acceleration. I can figure out the mathematics if someone can tell me how to draw the graph of a function in my view. Thanks in advance for any help I receive.

Comment: SKShapeNode to draw the path?

Comment: The only "future path" you can calculate easily just from velocity and acceleration is an elongation of the current position + velocity, ie a straight line pointing in the same direction the object is already moving in. The (advanced) alternatives depend on how you plan on predicting future movement, whether it's based on the most recent movement or historical data, and a couple other factors. If that's the question, it is too broad to answer here in a meaningful way.

Comment: Okay, then let's say that I can figure out an equation for the motion of the object. Given that, how would I go about drawing the path that the equation describes (preferably in polar coordinates, but Cartesian could work too)?